# How to exclude an app from lockdown mode?

Tags: ios

[About Lockdown Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212650) states:

> While your device is in Lockdown Mode, you can exclude an app or website in Safari from being impacted and limited. Exclude only trusted apps or websites and only if necessary.

I enabled lockdown mode on the device, restarted and started the app that I want to exclude. A dialog told me that lockdown mode is active for this app and I could exclude it in the settings, but I cannot.

Within the lockdown mode settings, I can only exclude websites. Within the app settings in the preferences there are only "Siri & Search" and "Background App Refresh" as options available.

How can I exclude a mobile app from lockdown mode? (The app that I try to make an exception for is Arc, the web browser.)